# cordova bluetooth plugin yuflow

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

In my ionic project I have installed cordova-plugin-bluetooth-yuflow using command:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-yuflow`

as mentioned in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/yuflow/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-yuflow).

But I coudn't execute function that allows me to enable bluetooth from my smartphone. I have a 5.1 android version. I want to use this plugin to connect to multiple serial bluetooth HC05

I don't understand what it is means:

> You can reach the plugin in your scripts at "window.bluetoothyuflow"

mentioned in the [plugin repo](https://github.com/yuflow/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-yuflow)

Comment: Could you ask this question as issue in the repository?

Comment: I asked this question as issue and I am waiting for an answer : https://github.com/yuflow/cordova-plugin-bluetooth-yuflow/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

You may be better of using a well documented and often used plugin, I recommend to use this Cordova plugin: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial (also take a look at the examples folder of this repo)

Comment: I have already used this plugin and I tested it with a single bluetooth HC05 and it works very well, but my problem is that I want to create an application that connects with multiple HC05 bluetooth module and with this plugin it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to type this in your javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
        bluetoothYuflow = window.bluetoothyuflow
        bluetoothYuflow.bluetooth(success, failure)

      }
```

Now on, when you have to call a function from yuflow type

```
bluetoothYuflow."yourfuncton"()
```